# Schedule a task in Plesk to update an xml file from a url

Tags: xml, cron, task, jobs, schedule

I would like to ask how is it possible to Schedule a task in Plesk to update an existing xml file (located in `/httpdocs`) from a url.

The problem is that I don't know which script is needed.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could use "curl" for example:

```
curl http://EXTERNAL-DOMAIN.COM/FILE-NAME.xml > /var/www/vhosts/YOUR-DOMAIN.COM/httpdocs/YOUR-FILE-NAME.xml
```